# Need Guidance for Cron Job Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I have a rails app. The rails app has many "Games", each game uses an API which I can use to see if the game is over. I want to set a cron job for each game to check every 10 minutes if the game is over or not, if it is, then stop the cron job for that game.

"rufus-scheduler" seems to be a legit easy gem. I'm just looking for some guidance in how to go about this. Do I store this in my controller when the game is created?

```
  scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
  scheduler.every '10m' do
    #look for game over, until game over
  end
```

Will the cron job continue to run if the controller is no longer active by the user? What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Why do you need per-Game cron entries?  That smells fishy to me as though there may be a better solution?

Comment: If you can think of one im open to it, but the website allows two users to "challenge" each other in an online video game. I have an api that allows me to check if each game is over or not. Think of anything better?

Comment: You were right too. Thanks Philip. Just didnt understand what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `rufus-scheduler` but I have used `whenever` and I believe `whenever` is a bit more used among the Rails community.

At any rate, to do it in rufus-scheduler I think you just add your rails code in 'every 10m' block. Let's say you create a class method on Game such as:

```
class Game
  def self.clean_ended_games
    #logic to clean/stop/remove cron for games that have ended
  end
end
```

then with rufus you would do the following inside `config/initializers/scheduler.rb`:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.every '10m' do
  Game.clean_ended_games
end
```

Using whenever would be very similar. Inside the `config/schedule.rb` file you would enter:

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "Game.clean_ended_games"
end
```

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for your answer! Any help is greatly appreciated. So your saying I would have two cron jobs running? One to check if the game is still going (because that is something that is needed, right?), and one to check all the games and remove the cron job from the ones that are over?

Comment: No, I don't know enough about what you are trying to do exactly to give help about what cron jobs should do or how many are needed. I just gave an example of setting up a cron with rufus and whenever.

Comment: After second thought, I think you should just have one cron job (scheduled independently outside of any controller) that runs and stops/cleans ANY games that have ended. I do not think you need multiple cron jobs.